# git ignores file although it's not into .gitignore

Tags: git

So the problem is that I'm given a project that I have to work on.
I have `config.yml` file that I'm editing, however it doesn't show up in the output of ``git status`. I checked`.gitignore`and`config.yml` is not in it.

But when I run this to see ignored files by git I see my file `config.yml`

```
git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
```

How come `config.yml` is ignored although it's not mentioned in `.gitignore`? And how do I exclude it from ignored files list?

> **UPDATE1**

`config.yml` is mentioned in another `.gitignore` that's why :/

Comment: is your config.yml inside a subdirectory? you might have other .gitignore files lying around (you can have one in each directory)

Comment: Maybe not the particular file is listed in the `.gitignore` rather than a directory where the file is located.

Comment: Check to see if you maybe have a global git ignore that might be preventing it. Although system specific, my global ignore resides in `~/.gitignore_global`

Comment: @ChrisMaes yes you're right, found another `.gitignore` in the same project :'(. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't figure out what's causing it to be ignored, a brute force solution to making it 'unignored' is to simply run

```
git add -f config.yaml
```

Git will then track that file.